# Detail and grouping data give a different result mysql

Tags: mysql

i have 2 queries, which is the first query get all detail data from a single table.

This is my first query command :

```
Select emp_num
     , program_detail
     , location_detail
     , price 
  from activities
 where status <> 3
 limit 40000
```

This command gave me 32,488 record with total price : 89.976.938.370

The second command was :

```
  select program_detail
       , count(emp_num)
       , sum(price) tot_price
    from activities
   where status <> 3
group by program_detail
```

this command gave me 14 records, with count of emp_num 32.488 and sum of price 89.976.938.799.

My question is : why the total of price from detail table and grouping tabel was different ?

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Your second query is invalid, and would not even run on certain versions of MySQL.  Please include sample data and output in your question, which might help to explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: i'd corrected my query in my next comment. i also paste my result when running those queries.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   program_detail, count(emp_num), sum(price) tot_price
FROM     activities
WHERE    status <> 3
GROUP BY program_detail
```

Comment: Sorry, i'd used group by command. So this is my correct command :

Select program_detail, count(emp_num) , sum(price) tot_price
  from activities
 where status <> 3 group by program_detail